# Invalid client secret provided MS Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory, blazor-server-side, azure-ad-graph-api

Trying to sign in users in my blazor server app via Microsoft Identity platform. I created a client scret, which is stored in secrets.json. Still it's giving me the above error:

AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret provided.

**Format of my secrets.json:**

```
{
  "AzureAD:ClientSecret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

**Part of my appsettings.json:**

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "TenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "",
    "ClientCertificates": []
  },
```

**Part of my Program.cs:**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var initialScopes = builder.Configuration["DownstreamApi:Scopes"]?.Split(' ') ?? builder.Configuration["MicrosoftGraph:Scopes"]?.Split(' ');

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches()
    .AddDownstreamWebApi("DownstreamApi", builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches()
.AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches()
.AddDownstreamWebApi("DownstreamApi",builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

What am I missing here?

Thank you in advance.

- Made sure I'm inserting the VALUE of the secret, not the ID
- Made sure the secret is not expired
- Made sure there is only one secret, not multiple ones
- Added all redirect URIs in my app registration
- My csproj file contains the UserSecretsId

Comment: Are you creating the secret with 2 year expiry? There was a Microsoft bug with this which corrupted secrets, try with a shorter date (even expiring a day earlier than 2 years)

Comment: Tried all different expiry options, unfortunately no change..

Comment: No the client secret I'm generating in the app registration

Comment: As of right now, my app is running locally, so there's no app service in place

Comment: I set up a new empty blazor project & let the whole Microsoft identity platform authentication be auto generated by Visual studio.. here everyhing is working fine. (with the same app registration and client secret). 
My blazor app wasn't set up with authentication when I first created it, so I added the authentication afterwards.. I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: No i don't have an app service

Comment: is there any update on this question now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for taking your time to look into my problem. Solved / found my mistake yesterday and immediately added a comment here which unfortunately wasn't saved somehow. I had a graphClient on another blazor component in my app, which was using another client secret (which obvisouly didn't exist anymore). That was causing the error. So really the rest was working perfectly fine. Thank you!

Comment: thanks for the update and you might delete the other answer your posted to end this question. Thanks in advance : ) by the way you can also pick this post as the answer by clicking the √ beside it to mark the solution.

Answer (score 0):

When we create the blazor server app with ms identity platform template, it will add the necessary codes and configuration for us to allow us sign in the blazor app with microsoft account. We do need to have an Azure AD app, but we don't need the client secret because client secret is used for authorization(generate access token to call api) but not the authentication(let users sign in)

[image]

Here's what we will have after creating the app via the template in appsettings.json. As you can see, no option for client secret.

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Domain": "qualified.domain.name",
  "TenantId": "22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222",
  "ClientId": "11111111-1111-1111-11111111111111111",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
},
```

Though I set up a wrong client secret, it won't bring me an invalid client secret error. So the first thing I want to confirm with you is that, you might create a new blazor server app with the template and fill the fields in appsettings.json first to check if your app could sign in you successfully.

[image]

I noticed that you have graph api tag inside your question so I think I need to add graph sdk into the app as well, then I can reproduce the same error as yours, adding graph sdk requires a correct client secret.

[image]

Then this is what I added based on the template project.

In program.cs, add graph sdk

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

add in the fetchData.razor page, have code like this.

```
@code {
    private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;
    
    [Inject]
    GraphServiceClient GraphClient { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var me = await GraphClient.Me.GetAsync();
        forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now));
    }
}
```

All the code above is based on packages like this:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.30.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph.Core" Version="3.0.11" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.15.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient" Version="2.15.1" />
<!-- using GraphServiceClient instead of MicrosoftGraph can solve error  -->
<!-- Could not load type 'Microsoft.Graph.IAutehnticationProviderOption' from assembly 'Microsoft.Graph.Core' -->
<!--<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph" Version="2.15.1" />-->
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="2.15.1" />
```

=======================================

I create a new blazor server app without choosing the identity platform. Then we firstly need to add the login component and added it into `MainLayout.razor`. We could copy the `LoginDisplay.razor` from `Shared` folder.

[image]

The next, in App.razor, surround all the code with `<CascadingAuthenticationState>`, or we will get error `InvalidOperationException: Authorization requires a cascading parameter of type Task<AuthenticationState>.`

[image]

Then configure the Program.cs,
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
.AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
.AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
//builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();//add ms identity handler
...
...

app.UseRouting();
app.MapControllers();//add mapController
app.MapBlazorHub();
```

Finally, add configurations in appsettings.json.

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Domain": "tenant_id",
  "TenantId": "tenant_id",
  "ClientId": "azure_Ad_client_id",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
  "ClientSecret": "client_secret"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That's what I did before, I created another new Blazor Server project, where I selected Authentication type via MS identity platform and installed the (necessary) ms identity tool and selected my app registration from Azure AD. Then everything is working fine, this app can successfully sign me in. But what about my existing app (I did not select MS identity platform as an identity provider when I first created my app)

Comment: let me have a try

Comment: updated and pls take a look at it....